# MotionLayout.TransitionListener not invoked if swiping fast enough

Tags: android, kotlin, android-motionlayout

I've been fiddling around with MotionLayout, and noticed that while everything works nice and dandy otherwise, the TransitionListener does not get invoked if I scroll quickly enough.

The layout is something like this (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
<MotionLayout>
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <NestedScrollView />
</MotionLayout>
```

The two `TextView`s are animated based on the `NestedScrollView`s scrolling, with a layout description like this:

```
<MotionScene>
    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded">

        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/contentScroll"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded">
        <!-- Set constraints for expanded state -->
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">
        <!-- Set constraints for expanded state -->
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Now, this works OK so far. To listen to the transition's progress, I've set a listener like this:

```
motionLayout.addTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionTrigger(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, triggerId: Int, positive: Boolean, progress: Float) {
        Timber.d("onTransitionTrigger")
    }

    override fun onTransitionStarted(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, startId: Int, endId: Int) {
        Timber.d("onTransitionStarted")
    }

    override fun onTransitionCompleted(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, currentId: Int) {
        Timber.d("onTransitionCompleted")
    }

    override fun onTransitionChange(motionLayout: MotionLayout?, startId: Int, endId: Int, progress: Float) {
        Timber.d("onTransitionChange: $progress")
    }
})
```

This works correctly and prints out stuff as I scroll the `NestedScrollView` slowly, but making a quick swipe, the listener won't get invoked at all (none of the listener's methods are invoked). The layout itself updates correctly, though.

Is there something I'm missing here, or is there a bug in the `MotionListener`'s invocation logic?

Comment: I've noticed that too - if transition finishes within 1 frame (very fast swipe or UI thread gets choked) listener is not invoked at all. Perhaps you'll have better luck filing a bug/feature request on projects github to get devs direct response on whether its intended or not.

Comment: Hey, did you figure out a solution or posted this issue on the tracker?

Answer (score 2):

Yes is is a know issue.
If the NestedScrollView transitions in less than a frame you do not get callbacks.
One workaround is to listen to the NestedScrollView

Answer (score 0):

yes it wont be invoked if its 1 frame ..instead ensure your motion scene is set up correctly. in my case i had two scenes one was a child of the other and i was trying to set the progress programatically. but it would not call the callbacks if its 1 frame (fling).

so instead don't depend on setting the progress programatically. use keyframes to pass the progress to the child scene:

from your parent scene:

```
<KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="0"
                app:motionTarget="@id/childScene"
                app:motionProgress="0" />

            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="100"
                app:motionTarget="@id/childScene"
                app:motionProgress="1" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
```

and yet another option is to execute commands from xml scene file itself. check out *keyTriggers* and *onCross* in the docs.

why are we doing this? because the xml code seems to be guaranteed to run even on a 1 frame pass, so we can trigger all things in xml scene file without a dependency on a programatic transition callback.